# Playwright doesn't show output for the webserver start in GitHub action

Tags: playwright

I use the config setting to start the webserver of the app I want to test om localhost.

```
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 1 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: [['list'], ['html', { open: 'never', outputFolder: 'playwright-report' }]],
  /* Test timeouts, set higher when running in CI */
  timeout: process.env.CI ? 60000 : 30000,
  expect: {
    timeout: process.env.CI ? 10000 : 5000,
  },
  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  webServer: {
    command: 'npm run web:dev',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    timeout: 300 * 1000,
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  },
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    ...proxyConfig(),
```

However on the CI machine, the localhost should - I think - be excluded from the proxy. However when I do this, the tests no longer seem to wait for the webServer to be started.

```
function proxyConfig() {
  if (process.env.PROXY) {
    return {
      proxy: {
        server: process.env.PROXY,
        bypass: 'http://localhost:3000',
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't see the output log from the webServer startup command in my GitHub action. When I run this on my local machine I DO see this output in the console. On my local machine everything works fine. Without this output its hard to know what is even happening.

So my main question here is: how do I get the output from the 'npm run web:dev' command to show up in GitHub actions?
I already tried the following, but it doesn't do anything:

```
  webServer: {
    command: 'npm run web:dev',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    timeout: 300 * 1000,
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    stdout: 'pipe', // <-- doesn't work
    stderr: 'pipe', // <-- doesn't work
  },
```

Setting this environment variable also does nothing:

```
export DEBUG=pw:webserver
```

I'm running Playwright 1.38 and want to test a NextJS app.